# Trello ios app deep-linking is not working

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, trello

I'm using Trello URL for deep-linking it's only open Trello board not specific card into Trello ios app:

I'm using this type of URLs:

1. https://trello.com/c/QquMg56H/24-bug-reports
2. https://trello.com/c/QquMg56H

Answer (score 0):

You can't because the configuration comes from the trello app itself. Unless they specify certain url path can open certain card.